# Keep current value in the cell with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I have some Google Sheet with 2 columns:

```
A  B  
a1  ..
a2 ..
.. b1
a2 b2
.. b3

.. means empty cell;
```

I want to fill column A with values from B if cell in B is filled.

In this example I want to get table:

```
A  B
a1  ..
a2 ..
b1 b1
b2 b2
b3 b3
```

I did something this:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B1));B1)
```

But in situation when B1 is empty but A1 isn't A1 getting "FALSE" instead of current value A1. 
How do I fix my snippet?

Comment: You get a value of `false` because you don&#39;t provide the 3rd argument to the `if` function (which is used when the tested predicate is not true)

Comment: You can have user assigned value in a cell or a formula, not both.  One will overwrite the other.  You will need code to do this.

Comment: You can have a third column with the formula that would put the value from B if there is one and the value from A otherwise, but you can't do this in place with a formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok, I did so with 3rd column.))